# Como dar push em branches remotos?

Tags: git

Possuo uma branch local chamada `ResultadoAPI`, a remota está localizada em **origin/feature/ResultadoAPI** 
Tentei dar push de diversas maneiras mas essa remota continua **desatualizada**

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git push origin origin/feature/ResultadoAPI 
Everything up-to-date
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git push origin ResultadoAPI 
Counting objects: 65, done.
```

O comando `git push origin ResultadoAPI` criou OUTRA remota e está dando push nele. Como faço para dar push corretamente no remoto? 
****UPDATE**

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git status
On branch ResultadoAPI
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/ResultadoAPI' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   oknok-commons/src/main/java/oknok/auth/AuthFilter.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Dou `git add -A`,`git commit -m "Nome do commit"`, o commit é feito com **sucesso** e tento dar push mas **não é possível**

Talvez o problema seja o `/`, porém mesmo com aspas não consigo dar push:

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git push origin "feature/ResultadoAPI"
error: src refspec feature/ResultadoAPI does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.sofist.com.br/oknok-clicktag.git'
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git push origin "origin/feature/ResultadoAPI"
Everything up-to-date
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git push origin "feature/ResultadoAPI:feature/ResultadoAPI"
error: src refspec feature/ResultadoAPI does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.sofist.com.br/oknok-clicktag.git'
```

Comment: Coloca o git status, você deu pull ?
se você estiver usando github em RP publico, posta o link

Comment: Sim, possui arquivos p commitar e está atualizada quando dou pull.

Comment: então, tenta 
git add --all
, git commit -a

Comment: Daniela. Pode tentar `git push -u origin ResultadoAPI:feature/ResultadoAPI`? Se der certo me avise.

Comment: Assumindo que você ainda tenha o galho e o projeto hehehe, não vi a data.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá,

primeiro veja como está seu repositório

```
git status
```

- Você esta no branch certo ?
- Tem commit faltando ?
- Branch está
  Desatualizado ?
- Nenhum dos anteriores ?

Caso branch errado

```
git checkout ResultadoAPI
```

Caso exista commit pendente...

```
commit -m "msg..commit"
```

Obs: pode ser que tenha que adicionar algum arquivo antes de dar commit então..

```
git add --all
git commit -a  ou git commit -m "commit"
```

caso exista novas atualizações

```
git pull origin  ResultadoAPI
```

Quando tudo estiver ok

```
git push origin ResultadoAPI
```

Se aparecer

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Está tudo OK, porém se mesmo assim não atualizar lá, provavelmente você está em um branch errado, ou não deu commit em suas atualizações, outra possibilidade é esquecer de adicionar alguma coisa no repositório.

```
git add --all
```

Comment: Como nos comentários anteriores, o problema não é este. Talvez seja por causa do "/"

Comment: E `git push origin ResultadoAPI` é a localização de "origin/ResultadoAPI" e não "origin/feature/ResultadoAPI"

Comment: Olha eu posso está errado, mas tem algo estranho,
modified:   oknok-commons/src/main/java/oknok/auth/AuthFilter.java

falta adicionar esse arquivo, certo ?

Comment: git add --all
não está adicionando ele ?

Comment: Isvaldo, em seguida comentei que adicionei os arquivos no commit. O problema não é fechar o commit ou atualizar a branch mas sim enviar estes commits para remoto (push).

Comment: Não sei se você já resolveu, isso está um pouco estranho, cria um novo branch e tenta enviar, git checkout -b Novo

Comment: Não consegui resolver isso, tive que criar outra branch mesmo =(

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
git remote -v
```

*Isto listará os repositórios remotos atualmente configurados*

Em seguida, faça o seguinte:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

*Em que ORIGINAL_OWNER é o seu user e ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY o nome do seu repositório original*

Confirme que ficou tudo configurado:

```
git remote -v
```

[Como configurar um remote para um fork - ajuda oficial](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/)